How to auto update my apk with GitHub without using Play Store with Kotlin?
What I need is to access my private repository with my token to the different branches that I have (one for each version), in each branch I have an apk, I would like to download that apk and install it, to be able to update my application.
class UpdateVersion{

    private  val GITHUB_TOKEN = ""
    private  val GITHUB_REPO_OWNER = ""
    private  val GITHUB_REPO_NAME = ""

    private  val GITHUB_API_BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com"

    fun downloadLatestApk(context: Context) {
        val client = OkHttpClient()

        val url = "$GITHUB_API_BASE_URL/repos/$GITHUB_REPO_OWNER/$GITHUB_REPO_NAME/branches"

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer $GITHUB_TOKEN")
            .build()

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                Log.i("Download", "Error: ${e.message}")
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val responseBody = response.body
                    responseBody?.let {
                        try {
                            val bodyString = it.string()
                            val branchesJsonArray = JSONArray(bodyString)
                            val latestVersion = findLatestVersion(branchesJsonArray)
                            latestVersion?.let { version ->
                                val downloadUrl = "$GITHUB_API_BASE_URL/$GITHUB_REPO_OWNER/$GITHUB_REPO_NAME/raw/App.apk"
                                downloadApkFromUrl(context, downloadUrl)
                                Log.i("sdsd",downloadUrl)
                            }
                        } catch (e: JSONException) {
                            Log.i("Download", "JSON error: ${e.message}")
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.i("Download", "Error response: ${response.code}")
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun findLatestVersion(branchesJsonArray: JSONArray): String? {
        if (branchesJsonArray.length() > 0) {
            val latestBranchObject = branchesJsonArray.getJSONObject(0)
            return latestBranchObject.getString("name")
        }
        return null
    }

    fun downloadApkFromUrl(context: Context, apkUrl: String) {
        val apkUri = Uri.parse(apkUrl)

        val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(apkUri).apply {
            setTitle("Downloading APK")
            setDescription("Downloading the APK file...")
            setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "App.apk")
            allowScanningByMediaScanner()
            setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        }

        downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    }

}

I hope I can get it, thank you

Use PackageInstaller to install your APK.
